# Android draw Rectangle but one corner is Rounded

Tags: android, canvas, draw

How to draw Rectangle ，and one corner is rounded?  I try to use drawRoundRect but it cannot draw only one corner is rounded.how to draw it ?

Comment: Show us the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this UI, you can use xml selector

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/white" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/light_gray" />
<padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
<corners android:topLeftRadius="6dp" android:topRightRadius="6dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

you can manage it by tag corners

```
<corners android:topLeftRadius="6dp" android:topRightRadius="6dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"/>
```

for more information you can visit shape drawable.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Answer (score 0):

**@Yogendra's** answer can be improved by completing xml background file lets say left_rounded.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#DAD9D9" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

This code is making Left corner rounded, you can make your own by using **corner** tag
Now setting it in background of a view suppose textView

```
 <TextView
         android:id="@id/pic_count"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:background="@drawable/left_rounded_grey"
         android:text="1"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:textSize="14sp" />
```